# How to plot interaction effects with individual-level variable and individual fixed-effects?

Tags: r, panel, lm, effects, marginal-effects

I have a dataset with individual `id` (factor), time `t` (factor), a dependent variable `y` (continuous) and an independent variable `x` (continuous), which can be measured at time t `xt` or can be set at the individual level `xi`.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(id=as.factor(rep(1:20, each = 5)),
           t=as.factor(rep(1:5, 20)),
           y=rnorm(100, 5, 2))
df$xt <- rep(rnorm(100, 0, 1))
df$xi <- rep(rnorm(20, 0, 1), each = 5)
```

I want to estimate the marginal effects (and plot) of the interaction of time and the individual level IV (`t:xi`) while controlling for individual fixed effects (`id`). I know that the FEs of `id` absorb the effects of `xi`, but I want to see the effect of the interaction `t:xi`. Below I show how this works with `t:xt` but does not work with `t:xi`.

```
m1 <- lm(y ~ t + xt + t:xt + id, df)
m2 <- lm(y ~ t + xi + t:xi + id, df)

Effect(focal.predictors = c("t", "xt"), mod = m1)
Effect(focal.predictors = c("t", "xi"), mod = m2)
```

I have tried different combinations to write the interaction term (`t + t:xi`, `t*xi`, etc.), and using different packages (`effects`, `ggeffects`, `interplot`, `margins`, etc.). Since there are coefficients for `t` and `t:xi`, I think there should be a way to estimate and plot these effects (using base-0/change). How could this be done?

Comment: In your `dff` I don't see a `xt` nor a `xi` variable. Is there a misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I renamed them for clarity. Should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

A less cumbersome way to estimate the same models that you posted in the answer to your own question would be to use the colon notation:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(id=as.factor(rep(1:20, each = 5)),
           t=as.factor(rep(1:5, 20)),
           y=rnorm(100, 5, 2))
df$xt <- rep(rnorm(100, 0, 1))
df$xi <- rep(rnorm(20, 0, 1), each = 5)
df$t2_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 2, df$xi, 0)
df$t3_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 3, df$xi, 0)
df$t4_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 4, df$xi, 0)
df$t5_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 5, df$xi, 0)

m1 <- lm(y ~ t + t : xt + id, df)
m2 <- lm(y ~ t + t : xi + id, df)
```

You may also want to consider [the `marginaleffects` package as an alternative](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) for computing and plotting adjusted predictions and marginal effects. (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

```r
library(marginaleffects)

plot_cap(m1, condition = c("xt", "t"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_cap(m2, condition = c("xi", "t"))
```

[image]

Comment: This does get the marginal effects to plot. However, it does not reflect the coefficients of the regression. Is there a way to make the `plot_cap` function to assume a `0` value for the id variables? Then I think it would only take into account the intercept and the effects of `t` and `t:xi`.

Comment: This is not possible in `marginaleffects`, and it is not possible in the `effects` package either. To get predictions both packages must supply a valid value for the `id` variable. If you just want to account for the intercept, then you are implicitly including the effect of the *omitted* / *reference* category. In my `m2`, for ex, the intercept refers to `id1`, since that is the category that the model omits.

Comment: There is no reference-free interpretation possible (a mathematical impossibility), but you can specify the `id` you want in the `predictions` function. For example, `predictions(m2, newdata = datagrid(id = 1, t = df$t, xi = -2:2))`

Comment: I understand there must be a reference. In this case, I would like the reference to be the intercept or adjust it to zero. Regarding the value given to `id`. Is there a way the model could return the predictions under the condition that the value for every `id` is zero?

Comment: When `id=1`, the reference IS the intercept, because `1` is the omitted category. So it sounds like `plot_cap()` is already giving you what you want. If you want the predictions to be centered at 0, you could substract 5.48774 (the estimated intercept) from the `predicted` column generated by the `predictions()` command in my previous comment.  `id=0` does not exist in your simulated data, so we can't make predictions for such a hypothetical individual. No `R` package will be able to give you that, because it is impossible.

Comment: Yes, this works. The only problem then is that the confidence intervals take into account the standard error of the effect of individual `id` 1. Is there a way the standard errors are based only on the effects of `t` and `xi`?

Comment: No, sorry, not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. It's a little clunky but it works. Basically, you have to create new variable for each interaction except for the first. It's not only that the individual FEs absorb the direct effect of `xi`, but they also absorb the interaction between `xi` and time `t1`. In other words, the baseline effect of `xi` in time 1 can be estimated based on the individual FEs.

```
df$t2_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 2, df$xi, 0)
df$t3_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 3, df$xi, 0)
df$t4_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 4, df$xi, 0)
df$t5_xi <- ifelse(df$t == 5, df$xi, 0)

m1 <- lm(y ~ t + t2_xi + t3_xi + t4_xi + t5_xi + id, df)

Effect(focal.predictors = c("t2_xi", "t3_xi", "t4_xi", "t5_xi"), mod = m1)
```